# Json response error on datatable

Tags: json

DataTables warning: table id=table4 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you input data is invalid or invalid format.

You might be sending empty or spacial characters.

Please share some input data, so it will be easy to solve your problem.

To check if the data is a valid json, try to check it [here](http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: Thanks man. I found out that my data is not a valid json. It helps me alot. I'm new to this thing, so I'm very thankful to you. :)